# strlen function always returning 0

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

For a homework assignment we have to write a short program that tells you the number of arguments passed to main, their data address, and what each argument is, using argc and argv.  We also had to write a function called strlen (we weren't allowed to use any similar functions included in a library) that computed the length of each argument passed to main by using pointers.  My function always returns 0.  Sorry that I am asking such a basic question, but as a first year student I am not trained in the use of a debugger yet. Here is my code:

```
int strlen(char * p)
{
    char X[50];
    p = &X[0];
    int i = 0;

    while (*(p + i) != '\0')
       i++;

    return i;
}
```

I've tried several different things to fix this but no matter what the function always seems to return the value 0.  Is there a glaringly huge issue I am overlooking?  Any nudge in the right direction would be helpful, but please don't just give me the answer.

Comment: You are assigning the value of `&X[0]` **to** `p` here -- `p = &X[0];`

Comment: "please don't just give me the answer" -- try [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  Explain to the duck what `X` is supposed to do.

Comment: If you have no reasoning for `char X[50];` and `p = &X[0];`, you might just drop these lines.

Comment: You realize `char X[50]` has indeterminate content right? You're never checking the length of the data referenced by the incoming **`char *p`**, losing it immediately by overriding the incoming address with that of a local automatic (and unnecessary) array. And just for consistency, `char* p` should be `const char *p` and the function should return `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem.  I knew I was overlooking something glaringly obvious!

Comment: actually it should not always return zero, because local variables are assigned garbage values unless explicitly initialized to zero

Comment: @mangusta: But a great many variables hold the value 0, so garbage has a higher probability of being 0.

Comment: The name `strlen` is reserved. Writing your own function with that name might cause unexpected behavior. For example, a call to `strlen` could call either your function or the standard function. Use a different name like `my_strlen`.

Comment: @MooingDuck everything i know is that only global and static variables are guaranteed to be initialized by zero

Comment: @mangusta: Absolutely correct.  You're right that this should not _always_ return 0.  However, since a great many variables hold 0, garbage has a higher probability of 0. If he always calls the same function before this, that makes it entirely _probable_ that _in his exact code_ the "garbage" starts with 0, and thus will _in his exact code_ always return 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote a function that calculates the length of local "string" `X`. Array `X` is not even initialized. It contains garbage. Your function returns the length of that garbage string. It is not necessarily `0`, it just accidentally happened to be zero in your experiments. In general case your function will return a garbage value or simply cause your program to crash. The behavior is undefined.

In other words, when you call your function as `strlen("hello")` the `"hello"` string is completely ignored by the code you wrote. Your function still insists on working with local array `X`, not with the argument string `"hello"` passed form the outside.

If it is you who wrote this function, it is really a question to you: why did you do it that way?

P.S. A more sensible implementation of `strlen` would probably receive a `const char *` parameter (not `char *`) and perform the counting in the domain of `size_t` type (not `int`).

P.P.S. `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`. Many people would find the latter more readable than the former.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something glaringly obvious but I overlooked it.  My program is working as intended now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your function makes no sense; it overwrites the parameter and array X is not initialized so its elements have some unspecified values and the program using this function has undefined behavior. 
The function could look like:

```
size_t strlen( const char * p )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while  ( *( p + i ) != '\0' ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

Or more readable

```
size_t strlen( const char * p )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while  ( p[i] != '\0' ) i++;

    return i;
}
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>

size_t strlen( const char * p )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while  ( p[i] != '\0' ) i++;

    return i;
}

int main()
{
   char s[] = "Hello gsoble";

   std::cout << "The size of the greeting is " << strlen( s ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the first two lines.

```
int strlen(char * p)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*(p + i) != '\0')
        i++;

    return i;
}
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/8R8Elu

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behaviour. You are passing `X` array till `'\0'` but `'\0'` may never happen as `X` is a local object with undefined value. You may instead experience a segmentation fault.

> Is there a glaringly huge issue I am overlooking?

You don't need local array. You can start just with

```
size_t strlen( const char * p) // take const for safety reasons
{                              // and return size_t for compatibility
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( *(p + i) != '\0') ++i;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's expected for `strlen(X)` in the code in the question -- but `X` isn't what the function should be looking at, and in fact `X` isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers explain, you're setting `p` equal to an uninitialized `x` here, which will give you undefined behavior. What the other answer don't give you however, is.....*recursion* (because why not)

```
unsigned strlen(const char *p) {
    if(*p == '\0') return 0;
    return 1 + strlen(p+1);
}
```

And if you wanted to get it down to 1 line:

```
unsigned strlen(const char *p) {
    return (*p == '\0') ? 0 : 1 + strlen(p+1);
}
```